# Sync Hotmail folders to apple "Mail"

Tags: email, data-synchronization, hotmail

I love the Mail application on my Mac and want to centralize and administer my Mail account here. However, I can't configure the Mail program to synchronize my *inbox*, the *sent* box and *other folders* I have defined.

When I sent a new mail from my Mac it creates a new sent folder under *mails sent*. Folders that appear in Outlook are not synchronized and other folders from POP ond Hotmail are not accessible either. I am running the Mail version 5.3.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It is quite difficult to understand what you are asking here. That is why I had to edit the question a bit radically - but some understanding issues remain. Please try to edit the question yourself again in an attempt to clarify what the exact problems/issues are that you are experiencing. Thank you! :)

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between the email protocols **IMAP** and **POP**? While changes in IMAP are pushed to a server so that they can be applied on all configured devices, changes in POP are locally.